# sencha touch list doesn't work after building app

Tags: list, extjs, build, sencha-touch, touch

I'm sure I'm missing something but I can't understand why a list that perfectly works in debug mode doesn't show in production.

Some details:
- the list is inside an Ext.navigation.View
- the list must show a filtered store by the itemtap event from another list
- the store reads from a remote json
- the build is for a web-app

this is the code I use to update the list:

```
listUpdate: function() {
    console.log("sections_list update " + this.section);
    section = this.section;

    this.setStore(Ext.getStore('sections_remote'));

    this.getStore().setFilters([function(item) {
        return item.get('section')==section
    }]);

    this.getStore().load({
        callback: function(records, operation, success) {
            console.log("sections_list loaded "+records.length);
            this.refresh();
        },
        scope: this
    });
}
```

after loading, the records.length is always the total length and not the number of the filtered records but in debug version the list shows only the filtered records while in production shows nothing.

any ideas?

thanks in advance,
Daniele

Comment: I'm not sure what could be happening, but since on build the JS code is compressed, it is important to have all semi-colons in place. You need one on the end of the filter line. Other than that, I'm really not sure. Interested to hear if you figure it out though.

Comment: When you say it shows nothing… do you mean its a blank list ? Can you try adding inline data to the list, and checking if that works, so that you'll know whether its a connection error or something else.

Comment: add in a alert box on the setFilters and load functions. Also add a global alert for the listUpdate function. That way you'll know when it's called (or not called in your case). Sometimes the order in which its being called, or the fact that sometimes its not called at all could be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just put all the semicolons and now it works.
Thank-you